# Ember application loads blank page in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, ember.js, internet-explorer-11, ember-cli

I have started my ember application in local and if it launched in chrome it works fine but when i give the URL in IE 11 a blank page is loading ...pls let me know how to fix it

Comment: Ember application don't have any known issues in IE11. . Look at the console, you might be having js loading problem or any api response problem. Please provide more info about the stuff you tried to debug which will be useful to answer.

Comment: not getting any console error @kumkanillam....when i load for 2nd time i m getting a issue like  multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode

Answer (score 1):

> multiple definitions of a property not allowed in strict mode

To resolve this error, you need to remove duplicated function/property name which is mentioned in console. At any point of time you should have only one function/property with the same name.
for examle say,

```
export default Component.extend({
    foo: function(){
        //foo function
    },
    foo: function(){
        //this will produce error in IE strict mode and it will not execute JS
    }
});
```

Comment: got it @kumkanillam doing the same